# Angularjs submit ng-model indexed data to controller

Tags: angularjs, select, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angularjs and have multiple selects generated with ng-repeat as follows...

```
                                            <table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in paramMapByCmd">
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input  type="hidden" ng-model="myData.param" value="{{key}}" /><label>{{key}}:</label></td>
        <!--                <td><input type="text" ng-model="myData.param[i]" /></td> -->

                        <td>
                            <select name="param_val_sel" ng-options="item as item for item in value track by $index" 
                                    ng-model="myData.paramValue[$index]"
                                    ng-change="changeParamValue()">
                                <option value="">Select Parameter Value</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>               
                    </tr>    
            </table>
```

now when the form gets submitted how do I retrieve the array (hopefully it's an array ?) in the controller?

```
$scope.submitCmd = function() {

    var comData = $scope.myData.command;
    use a loop here....
    ????var paramData = $scope.tl1Data.paramValue[$index]; ????
```

How do you do this?

P.S. I've added more html to show the ng-repeat...

Comment: Can you please show full form in html?!

Comment: usually you would have everything in form `ng-model`'s bound to one object , each `ng-model` with it's own property, and just send that object containing the whole form data to server

Comment: The $index variable is a special value that exists only inside the view ng-repeat directive. You can't use in the controller.

Comment: I'm not sure what the $[index ] does to get the data posted back to the Angular controller. The selects get created dynamically off a LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> ... $scope.paramMapByCmd = result;

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example with `ng-options`

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.selectedItem = {};
  $scope.items = [{name: 'one', id: 30 },{ name: 'two', id: 27 },{ name: 'threex', id: 50 }];
});
```

**View**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>selected item is : {{selectedItem}}</p>

  <p> name of selected item is : {{selectedItem.name}} </p>

  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>
</body>
```

Your selected result in this case will be in `$scope.selectedItem`. It means that your result should be in variable that you put in `ng-model`

[Here is the plunker with example](http://plnkr.co/edit/X1eIiD?p=preview)

In your case you don't need in `$index` in `ng-model`you can keep it like this `ng-model="tl1Data.paramValue"` and then check your scope in controller
like `console.log($scope.tl1Data.paramValue)`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `$scope.tl1Data.paramValue` already stores an array.
To iterate over it you could do something like this:

```
for(item in $scope.tl1Data.paramValue) {
    console.log(item);
}
```